# Next JS + StoryBook - error if i write styles to module.scss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, next.js, storybook

When i write some styles to my file ButtonWidget.scss i get error in console when write command

- yarn storybook

Erro Code:

```
 ERROR in ./src/components/ButtonWidget/ButtonWidget.module.scss 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .button {
|   width: 100%;
|   font-size: 0.875em;
 @ ./src/components/ButtonWidget/ButtonWidget.tsx 3:0-48 11:26-32 @ ./src/components/ButtonWidget/ButtonWidget.stories.tsx
 @ ./src sync ^\.(?:(?:^|[\\/]|(?:(?:(?!(?:^|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$
 @ ./generated-stories-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined ./storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/preview/config-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addParameter.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-outline/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-interactions/dist/esm/preset/argsEnhancers.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./generated-stories-entry.js
```

if i remove styles - all working

My main.js is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
};
```

My ButtonWidget:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
import React from 'react';
import { TButtonWidget } from './@types';
import styles from './ButtonWidget.module.scss';

export function ButtonWidget(props: TButtonWidget) {
  const { title, className, callBack } = props;

  return (
    <button onClick={callBack} className={classNames(styles.button, className)}>
      {title}
    </button>
  );
}
```

My commented ButtonWidget.module.scss

```
// .button {
//   width: 100%;
//   font-size: 0.875em;
//   font-weight: 700;
//   text-align: center;
//   padding: 1em 0;
//   background-color: yellow;
//   border-radius: 5px;
//   text-decoration: none;
//   color: black;
//   border: none;
//   transition: all 0.3s linear;
//   box-shadow: 2px 4px 6px rgba(37, 48, 149, 0.25);
//   cursor: pointer;

//   &:active {
//     background-color: rgb(176, 176, 1);
//   }
// }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, we need downgrade sass version